# Write UIImage to path with gps coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, uiimage

In my app i have created a custom camera viewcontroller and i would like to save the image in the documents folder under a specific path with the image's location info.
This is how i save the image now:

```
NSData* originalImageJpegRepresentation = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.cameraSnapshotImage, 90);
[originalImageJpegRepresentation writeToFile:[self.targetDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
```

But the image doesn't contain the location info in its exif data after i read it.

I do have the geo location at the time i wish to save it in a `CLLocation*` object.

How can i add its coordinate to the saved image?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom subclass of NSObject and then use NSCoding to manually store and retrieve the image data and location data.

```
@interface MyImageData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *location;

@end

@implementation MyImageData

...

#pragma mark NSCoding

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, 90);
    [encoder encodeObject:originalImageJpegRepresentation forKey:@"image"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_location forKey:@"location"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSData *imageData = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"];
        _image = = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        _location = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"location"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you can save an instance of this class to file and it will include both data items.

```
MyImageData *myImageData = ...

[myImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `ALAssetsLibrary` to save the gps data using the `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` method.  Read up on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ALAssetsLibrary)